# Trouble logging in to shopify programatically

Tags: authentication, shopify

i am trying to use shopify for a client and that client has one particular need that i'm not sure if i can satisfy. I need to be able to bypass the standard login page. i was hoping i could set up a seperate login page outside of the shopify store, and if they pass validation log the user into the shopify store programatically. Does anyone know if this can be done? I am more of a front end developer and i can't seem to get any help from shopify on this one.

Comment: have you tried to change login page ?

Answer (score 0):

It is trivial to password protect a Shopify store, but provide a separate login that then authenticates. Use Mechanize. It works.

Comment: OK I will have a look into that.